# Is it possible to pass this in javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie to javascript. In javascript i am creating a html checkbox and inserting into a specified div. An onclick function is called within the checkbox html. I have to either pass the entire `this` in the function or just `checked` attribute in the function. For better clarity here's my code

```
childrens = childrens + "<div class='span4'><input type='checkbox' class='checkcheck' onclick = 'fillin("+this+");' name='"+name+"' alt='"+fromwhere+"' title='"+key+"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;"+name+"</input></div>";<br>

<script>
    function fillin(test)
    {
        alert(test);
    }
</script>
```

Am i on the correct path?I have to check if the checkbox is checked or not.

> PS: fromwhere,key,name changes dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change -

```
childrens = childrens + "<div class='span4'><input type='checkbox' class='checkcheck' onclick = 'fillin("+this+");' name='"+name+"' alt='"+fromwhere+"' title='"+key+"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;"+name+"</input></div>";
```

To -

```
childrens = childrens + "<div class='span4'><input type='checkbox' class='checkcheck' onclick = 'fillin(this)' name='"+name+"' alt='"+fromwhere+"' title='"+key+"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;"+name+"</input></div>";
```

The checkbox element will be passed to the `fillin()` function. Notice that I have moved 'this' from outside the srtring to inside it.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to pass `this` in a javascript function (it's just a object).

```
onclick ="filling(this);"
```

Should work, it passes the input-element to the function.

Comment: am getting the following error `SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
fillin([object Object]);`

Comment: Could you post your javascript code where this error is being thrown?

Answer (score 1):

No, on click `this` should refer to the checkbox element. So you need to embed `this` in the string:

```
... onclick="fillin(this);" ...
```

While check for `checked` can be done so:

```
function fillin(test) {
    if (test.checked) { ... }
}
```

Comment: am getting this error `SyntaxError: missing ] after element list fillin([object Object]);`

Comment: @Vinay How do you add checkbox elements?